# Bitwise operator that "cancels out" after being applied k times

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

XOR is an operator that "cancels out" after being applied 2 times, in the sense that `x ^ x = 0` for any `x`.

Is it possible to design (perhaps by composing XOR/AND/OR/NOT in some way?) a bitwise operator `$`, such that `x $ x $ ... $ x` (k `x`s in total) evaluates to 0 for any `x`?

Comment: Are you talking about integer values for `x`? Is the `$` operator restricted to operating bitwise? Is `k` a given fixed constant? Does the value of `x $ x ... $ x` have to be non-zero for non-zero `x` and any number of applications less than `k`?

Comment: What is the practical use of this hypothetical operator? If this is just a theoretical exercise, then it's not really a practical programming problem. (That said: There are only 16 possible operators that can be built out of XOR, AND, OR, and NOT. You can brute-force the solution.)

Comment: XOR doesn't "cancels out after being applied 2 times". It cancels out after being applied an even number of times

Comment: No matter how you cut it, a bit only has two states. So a cycle length greater than two is not possible without some external state. If you are prepared to work on groups of bits, then you could manage something, but it wouldn't be bitwise any more.

Comment: Fun-fact: `OR` and `NOT` is sufficient to construct any logical operator (see minecraft or basic logic, whichever you prefer). And there's a bunch of other operator-groups that can do this. `x AND NOT x` is quite reliably 0 for any `x`. Possibilities are limitless. You could even try to stumble something together from rotation and xor together to zero out a sequence of sufficient length, though thats already a bit trickier. Basically the options are limitless.

Comment: XOR cancelling out is *x ^ y ^ y == x* for all values of *x* & *y*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example if the $ operator is defined such that `x $ y = 0` for any x or y, then it will have the property you describe.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
(x1 ^ x2) | (x1 ^ x3) | (x1 ^ x4) | ... | (x1 ^ xk)
```

This will only return 0 if all the `x` are the same. Or even simpler replace `$` by `==`: `x == x == x ...` if that is allowed... only works mathematically but wouldn't work in Java.